# C# Windows Forms Windows Media Player No Picture

Tags: c#, winforms, wmp

I need an advice, I have a C# windows forms application that use WMP (WMPLib.dll and AxInterop. WMPLib. dll). I tried an application and it works OK on all computers except one. That computer is on Windows XP. When I try to play video, player load video, shows total time, start playing the video, but there is no picture, only black screen. When I try to play the same video on windows media player on same computer everything works fine. I tested the app on other Win XP computers and everything works OK.

So far I reinstall WMP, reinstall all codecs, remove all other players but that didn't help.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, what else I can check or what I can do to fix this.

---

**UPDATE**

I found out that when I turn off [windowless option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562473%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) video image is displayed. I use the windowless option to be able to capture images of video playback. Without that option I'm not able to capture screen with this code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(wmPlayer.Width-26, wmPlayer.Height-66);
            {
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
                {
                    Graphics gg = wmPlayer.CreateGraphics();
                    {
                        this.BringToFront();

                           g.CopyFromScreen(
                            wmPlayer.PointToScreen(
                                new System.Drawing.Point()).X+13,
                            wmPlayer.PointToScreen(
                                new System.Drawing.Point()).Y,
                            0, 0,
                            new System.Drawing.Size(
                                wmPlayer.Width-26,
                                wmPlayer.Height-66)
                            );
                    }
                }
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()){
                        bitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                        ret = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
                        pictureBoxSlika.Image=ret;



                    }
                }
            bitmap.Dispose();
```

How to make this windowless option to work on all computers?

Answer (score 0):

When shipping applications .. make sure that the target systems is compatible with your .NET framework version and .dll files version you used to develop you application.

Probably you are using a wmp.dll file version that is higher than what windows XP already have .

Always check for compatibility with what you used inside your application .

**According to 05-31-2014 Question Edit :**

You will need to use a namespace that belongs to Silverlight `System.Windows.Interop`

consider reading more [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) then [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.settings.windowless%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to know more about `Windowless` and `Interop`

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I developed an application with WMP 11 and I installed WMP 11 on that machine. Is there any way to embed all in the application so I don't need to rely on what is installed on the client machine?